# Schengen Visa Refused Twice by the French Embassy

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

me, my mother & my cousin applied for a Schengen visa together but my cousin's visa got accepted at once while mine & my mother's got rejected twice. The reason they gave was intended stay is not reliable (the vague answer). We applied thorugh an agent and submitted all the correct documents.I am working and submitted my NOC, my mother is a housewife, submitted her bank statement along with my fathers id and ITR and bank statement.

Please suggest here.....very disappointed. :(

Comment: Any unusual and unexplained entries in bank statements? Past travel history anomalies?

Comment: Consider not using an "agent" to apply for a visa. We have heard many stories of unscrupulous agents who file visa applications with fake information and documents, causing people to get visa refused and sometimes banned from countries. Sometimes they don't even file anything and send you a fake refusal letter! The agent still has your money though.